# Obtaining free satellite imagery for Australian floods?

Tags: data, remote-sensing, imagery, australia, flood

How can I obtain free satellite imagery for Australia? I want to find the extend of flood in specific time. I have already tried land-sat.But unfortunately there is no data available for that specific period.

Comment: Have you searched the data accessible on the Geoscience Australia website? http://www.ga.gov.au/search/index.html

Comment: For which year do you need data ?

Comment: at cost http://au.nearmap.com/ has historical imagery for floods - it is expensive to get satellites into orbit.

Comment: I need data for March 2012 NSW flood

Answer (score 2):

[ASTER](http://asterweb.jpl.nasa.gov/) and [MODIS](http://modis.gsfc.nasa.gov/) both have global coverage and are suited for larger scale flood analysis.  ASTER has a temporal resolution of 16 days and contains 14 spectral bands in VNIR (15m), SWIR (30m) and TIR (90m).  Note that ASTER SWIR data acquired from late April 2008 to the present exhibit anomalous saturation of values and anomalous striping.  MODIS has a higher return rate (1-2 days), although has a lower spatial resolution (500m, 1km) than ASTER.  They are available from a variety of sources:

1. [Earth Explorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/)
2. [Glovis](http://glovis.usgs.gov/)
3. [Reverb](http://reverb.echo.nasa.gov/reverb/#utf8=%E2%9C%93&spatial_map=satellite&spatial_type=rectangle)

Comment: @Mike: to compliment this answer have you seen the [Dartmouth Flood Observatory](http://floodobservatory.colorado.edu/) website?